# Unable to rotate Interface Orientation issue in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, orientation

I have a app which i want to display in portrait mode. But I only want to show one view in both modes.

I have do this for iOS5 . But in iOS6,i can't able to do this.

I also tried many codes to solved it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The answer to the question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073057/turning-off-use-autolayout-causes-app-to-only-run-in-portrait-mode) may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812484/ios-6-orientation-issues/15698391#15698391 which relevant to your question.

Answer (score 4):

apple has changed orientation in ios 6 .

in short use following steps:

> 1) set supported orientations in Targets->Summary...

[image]

> 2)In iOS6.0 `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` Method is
>   deprecated.So,instead of this method we have to use `shouldAutorotate`
>   Method.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {

   return NO;

  }
```

> 3) in method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` we have to set which
>   orientations we want like `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` if we want
>   all orientations

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
  {
return  (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |     UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown );

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply! But `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method is called only once & when i rotate i also take Landscape mode.